# Losing unicode during passing unicode char

Tags: php

I want to store in array pairs of unicode chars (char, number of instances of the char), but I have some problem with passing unicode chars:

This code:

```
$str = 'ółś';

var_dump(str_split($str));
```

displays:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "�"
}
```

And i don't understand what's wrong

But this code:

```
$arr = array('ó' => 1, 'ł' => 1, 'ś' => 1);
var_dump($arr);
```

displays:

```
array(3) {
  ["ó"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ł"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ś"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

and for me it is a result, which I want to achive.

**EDIT:**

Replacement for str_split (length=1) for unicode chars:

```
function mb_str_split( $string ) {
    # Split at all position not after the start: ^
    # and not before the end: $
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
}
```

[source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#99851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP string functions, like [**str_split()**](https://www.php.net/str_split) work on **bytes**, and not **characters**.

And when using UTF-8, each character can need more than one byte to be represented -- which means PHP string functions don't always work.

To manipulate strings in UTF-8, you should use the [**mbstring**][2] extension, which provides functions to manipulate multibyte strings.

In your case, I'm not sure which function of mbstring you should use ; maybe [**mb_split()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) ?

*It seems to do more than `str_split()`, but might help anyway...*

Comment: I found replacement for str_split in my case. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun ! And remember mbstring functions : you'll need those more often than you think ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Drop in replacement (with support for $split_length parameter):

```
function mb_str_split ($string, $split_length = -1) 
{
    if ($split_length == -1) {
        $split_length = 1;
    }

    for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen ($string, 'UTF-8'); $i < $len; $i += $split_length) {
        $array[] = mb_substr ($string, $i, $split_length, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $array;
}
```